# Выбор N случайных файлов из директории

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Необходимо скопировать из директории `N` случайно выбранных файлов.

Пока сделал так:

`ls -d /anydir/* | shuf | head -30 | xargs cp -t /tmp/othdir`

Можно ли сделать это проще, сократив конвейер?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**оговорка:** подразумевается, что, во-первых, в именах файлов нет специсимволов, например, пробелов, и во-вторых, длина (в байтах) списка файлов в каталоге не превышает максимальной длины списка аргументов, которую можно узнать, например, командой:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

---

1. у программы *shuf* есть опция `-e`, благодаря которой программа воспринимает другие аргументы как элементы входного списка (который и перемешиват:

   ```
   $ shuf -e 1 2 3
   1
   3
   2
   ```

   т.е., можно убрать одну «трубу» и вызов одной программы (*ls*)
2. а ещё у этой программы есть опция `-n`, поволяющая обойтись без вызова программы *head* (и ещё одной «трубы»)
3. в данном конкретном случае можно обойтись и без вызова программы *xargs* (и убрать ещё одну «трубу»), передав полученный список аргументов непосредственно программе *cp*:

   ```
   $ cp $(...) куда-копировать
   ```

---

итого как-нибудь так:

```
$ cp $(shuf -n 30 -e каталог/*) куда
```

Comment: это всё чревато переполнением списка аргументов на больших каталогах... трубы и `xargs` в этом отношении надёжней...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, цитирую: «2. **в данном случае** можно ...»

Comment: а опцию -n я и не заметил!

Comment: этот коментарий был скорее про `-e`... это не говоря про вечные грабли с пробелами в именах...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну, если стоит задача «сделать понадёжнее», надо, конечно, команду не сокращать, а ещё удлинять.

Comment: незначительно... у меня вот такой поиск «что посмотреть сегодня вечером» по файлопомойке в закладках: `find -regex '.*\.\(mkv\|avi\|mp4\|mpg\)' | shuf -n 5 | xargs -d'\n' smplayer`... не рассчитан разве что на переводы строк в именах... да и это добавит лишь по одному элементу к конвейеру....

Comment: @Fat-Zer, переводы строк могут встретиться в именах, а вот нулевые символы — точно нет. потому надёжней будет `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`

Answer (score 4):

> #### man shuf
>
> ```
>   -n, --head-count=COUNT
>          output at most COUNT lines
> ```

```
ls /anydir/ | shuf -n 30 | xargs cp -t /tmp/othdir
```